# Fatal error: Call to undefined function redirect() in dev/add_comment.php on line 19

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

Im not sure if im just having a problem with the redirect or also with some other lines
so here are my files
add_comment.php

```
<?php

include ('connection.php');

$id = $_GET['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$date = date('F j<\s\up>S</\s\up>, Y');
//$expire = time()+60*60*24*30;
//setcookie('name', $_POST['name'], $expire, '/');
//setcookie('email', $_POST['email'], $expire, '/');
//setcookie('website', $_POST['website'], $expire, '/');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO blog_comments (post_id,name,email,website,content,date) VALUES ('".$id."', '".$name."', '".$email."', '".$website."', '".$content."', '".$date."')");

mysql_query("UPDATE blog_posts SET num_comments=num_comments+1 WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
redirect('dev/view_post.php?id='.$_GET['id'].'#post-'.mysql_insert_id());
?>
```

post_view.php

```
    <?php
// post_view.php
include ('connection.php');
//get id from the link
$id = $_GET['id'];


$query = "SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE id = '$id'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo '<h2>'.$row['title'].'</h2>';
    echo '<em>Posted '.date('F j<\s\up>S</\s\up>, Y', $row['date_posted']).'</em><br/>';
    echo nl2br($row['post_content']).'<br/>';
    echo '<a href="dev/edit_post.php?id='.$_GET['id'].'">Edit</a> | <a href="dev/delete_post.php?id='.$_GET['id'].'">Delete</a> | <a href="dev/blog.php">View All</a>';
} 




//comments section
echo '<hr/>';
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM blog_comments where post_id = '$id' ORDER BY date ASC";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    echo $row2['name'];
}


echo '</ol>';

echo <<<HTML
<form method="post" action="dev/add_comment.php?id={$_GET['id']}">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="name">Name:</label></td>
            <td><input name="name" id="name"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="email">Email:</label></td>
            <td><input name="email" id="email"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="website">Website:</label></td>
            <td><input name="website" id="website"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="content">Comments:</label></td>
            <td><textarea name="content" id="content"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Post Comment"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
HTML;
?>
```

What must be the problem?
Im new to php. Thanks guys
I'm getting the error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function redirect() in dev/add_comment.php on line 19"

Answer (score 2):

`redirect()` is neither a PHP function or a defined function in your script. If you are trying to redirect, use `header()`:

```
header("location: dev/view_post.php?id='.$_GET['id'].'#post-'.mysql_insert_id()");
exit(); //note, I didn't test this for single/double quote accuracy, that's on you
```

Comment: Do I have to create a function and put that code inside the function?

Comment: It's not going to create itself ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'dev/view_post.php?id='.$_GET['id'].'#post-'.mysql_insert_id();
header('Location:'.$url);
```

Comment: It's one thing to answer, it's another to explain. Better answers are explained. Just a heads up :)

Comment: Everyone will follow her own way.. you follow your way of answer the question, another thing you just keep watch other's answer.. don't justify others

Comment: Justify? I gave a friendly tip which you warped into something that offended you. You do what you want to do, I was just trying to help you.